# Loop through var from LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

My ultimate aim is to loop through a LINQ query, but I am not even sure that my query is doing what I am expecting.

The query below is supposed select only distinct names from SQL server DB. It does not throw an error, but I can't test it as I can't seem to get the syntax correct to loop through the variable.

```
var staffNames = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Select(item => item.Staff_Name).Distinct();
```

My for loop is below, but obviously is not correct. I am getting the red underline on both the `staffNames.lenght` and `staffNames[i]`

```
            for (int i = 0; i < staffNames.lenght; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(staffNames[i]);
            }
```

I tried this as well just to test if the results from the query is correct with no luck. Also here as well `item`

```
             foreach (var item in staffNames)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item);
            }
```

[image]

Changed everything still an error,

[image]

Comment: What are the results?

Comment: @BabakNaffas, I am not sure, I can't loop through the variable to get the results.

Comment: You have a typo in length. I think it should be Length or Count

Comment: And you could consider using a foreach loop.

Comment: @Hosney. Ahh, yes the length intellisense was not showing, but this clears up that error. `staffNames.Count()` However, still an error here `staffNames[i]`

Comment: @KyloRen, What's the error?

Comment: @Hosney, last section in my question shows a `foreach` loop, not working fro me.

Comment: take a screen shot

Comment: What's the error with the foreach loop though?

Comment: @Hosney, red line under `item` in the message box

Comment: no one notice my answer i think :3 feels bad man

Comment: So the error now is gone, dig the other errors and include the errors in your console

Comment: item.ToString(); and no need in ToList() - Distinct returns IEnumerable

Comment: @Katana, i am still getting an error with that. `item`

Comment: yan convert item to string and please remove the for loop in top its kinda distractive

Comment: @AlekseyL., that does not work for me, I am still getting an error. Could the variable name be causeing conflicts?

Comment: Check `Staff_Time_TBL` row to see it has Staff_Name property or not, You might have spelled it wrong.

Comment: this giving us headache you need to practice debugging seriously. There are many ways to debug code using VS. Using console, add watch, using breakpoints please utilize this features. :) so the creator will not be mad

Comment: What is exactly the error in output window when you Build your solution ?

Comment: KyloRen, what data type is `Staff_No`? Because the first query selects `Staff_Name` and the second selects `Staff_No` . And from your update right now: ToString -> ToString()

Comment: @Katana, you think I did not try that before coming here?

Comment: `ToString()` and not `ToString`. It is a method and not a property

Comment: So dont just add obvious errors that you can solve yourself. Even that read lines give hints. Sorry for this

Comment: @Katana, if I could have solved the problems myself I would not be here, that is very much for sure. I realize there red lines indicated an error, but for all that I could research , I could not find out why I was getting the error.  Why is it so hard for people on Stackoverflow to not understand this? Obviously I am just starting out in C#, once again SO confirms that it is not for someone starting out.

Comment: @KyloRen ok sorry for my rudeness this is one way to push you to learn like how I learn from the past

Comment: @Katana. I appreciated the help. 日本人ですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple foreach will do the trick,

```
var staffNames = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Select(item => item.Staff_Name).Distinct();

foreach(var name in staffNames)
{
   MessageBox.Show(name.ToString());
}
```

**Or:**

```
var staffNames = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Select(item => item.Staff_Name).Distinct().ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < staffNames.Count; i++)
{
     MessageBox.Show(staffNames[i].ToString());
}
```

Things to note, staffNames is `IQueryable` and it **doesn't hold any data unless you enumerate it** (Loop through it). That's why you don't have `Length` property or `indexer` `[i]`. However, `IQueryable` implements `IEnumerable`. So you can Iterate through it using a `foreach`. Only when you start iterating over it (using `foreach` or `ToList()`, then **the database call is done**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a result that is an implements `IEnumerable` interface

So for this instance I added `ToList()` so i can enumerate the result.

```
var staffNames = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Select(item => item.Staff_Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

So you can iterate it using the following:

```
foreach (var item in staffNames)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
  }
```

Comment: You can iterate through an IEnumerable. It isn't necessary to convert to list.

Comment: instance of `IEnumerable`. You can't have an instance from an interface ?

Comment: You still don't need the ToList here

Answer (score 2):

`MessageBox` can only display string. The problem is you are giving it a wrong parameter type. Try `MessageBox.Show(staffNames[i].ToString());` `MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());`

Comment: That fixed everything thank you. How would you do the same for the non `foreach` loop?

Comment: @KyloRen He already mentioned that `staffNames[i].ToString()`

Comment: @my bad, I didn't see that. Thanks for the heads up.